# SERVER showing METRO logo and bundler instead of react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, metro-bundler

Whenever I am running command `npx react-native run-android` it is starting node server and showing **METRO** logo instead of usual **react-native** logo in server. for reference you can see the picture below.

[image: Showing METRO logo instead of react-native logo]

here a list of what I want to know:

> 1. how to get it back to usual react-native logo like simple projects?
> 2. what are the possible differences/causes of this happening and why is it happening?

Comment: please help if anyone is expert in react-native

Comment: But did it work?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if it work for you

Comment: @Pirogrammer, thanks but wont it have issues with future projects? also template looks a bit different, sorry I am new to react-native and cant find any solution to that.

Comment: I don't think so i have the same problem but it doesn't effect any of my projects I will try to find a solution.

Comment: Also if you new to react-native it better to start with the `expo-cli ` it more simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for taking so long, i found why it shows metro logo, there is no problem it's from the react native version if you really wanna see the react native logo you can downgrade some versions until it shows react native logo. But I think you can stick with the current version or newest version, because it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this behavior and I started doing some research on this as well, and after few hours of research I found out that it was due to the use of react-native version 0.64.0 (latest as of today). I tried to revert it back 0.63.4 (previous version) and it showed normal React logo. There's no any side affect or anything, I think they boost up the compilation process or something (I am not sure).